# security limits max files that can be open

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

how many files can a server have open?

is it based on the ram/cpu?

`/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
*    soft     nproc       65536
*    hard     nproc       65536
*    soft     nofile      65536
*    hard     nofile      65536
root soft     nproc       65536
root hard     nproc       65536
root soft     nofile      65536
root hard     nofile      65536
```

i used this to increase the limits, but i'm wondering if that number `65536` can be made larger?

Also, does `* sfot nproc` also cover `root soft nproc`? or does it need to be spcified for `root` and `*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `nofile` can be larger than 65536.

It's done intentionally since these limits are applied to the user and `*` can be overridden by setting the username for example on the server running Oracle DB I use\

`oracle soft nofile 104854`

Comment: ah, so in that case root is not needed since all limits are the same. gotcha. thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Eli some nice [ref in man](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf)